# How to jump from key-value pairs in a dictionary to create a list of cycle

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration, key-value

In my homework, a cycle is defined as a set of keys that jump from key -> value -> key that returns to its original starting value. For instance:

```
d1 = {1:6, 3:1, 6:3}
cycles = [[1, 6, 3]]
```

because 1:6 -> 6:3 -> 3:1, and the starting key == last value

Similarly for the following dictionary:

```
d1 = {1: 5, 2: 14, 3: 15, 4: 3, 5: 5, 6: 5, 
      7: 15, 8: 6, 9: 10, 10: 15, 11: 12, 
      12: 15, 13: 14, 14: 8, 15: 9}
```

Properly ordered, the cycles given by the mapping are: `[[5], [9, 10, 15]]`
(also because 5:5 is a complete cycle, and 9:10 -> 10:15 -> 15:9)
Is there a way to create a loop to track these cycles in dictionaries? I wish to create a line that would work for any random key-value dictionary mappings.

```
cycle=[]
For k,v in d1.items():
    if k == v:
        cycle.append([k])

For k,v in mapping2.items
    if k!=v:
        if v in keys:
            start_k = k

If mapping[k] in keys:
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Can you describe the algorithm you want to follow in plain English?

Comment: I wish to create a loop that can list out the keys from the dictionary which complete a "cycle" (for 1:1 [1] would be a cycle and in 1:3, 3:1 then [1,3] would be a cycle]

Answer (score 0):

This answer explains one potential algorithm, but doesn't implement it.
If you want to find an algorithm yourself, then stop reading.

There might be smarter ways, but one way would be.
If you have a dict with n keys, then you would need n iterations to detect all potential cycles.

Let's call the initial dict d and assume it has N (upper case N) key/value pairs

1.) make a copy of d
cpy = dict(d)

Initial iteration for cycle length n=1:
look for all keys in cpy, where  cpy[key] == key

add these to a list of solutions and remove these entries from the copied dict

First iteration for cycle length n=2:
create a new dict cpy2 the following way:
for each key of cp create a val, that is calculated `d[cp[key]]`
now assign cpy2 to cpy `cpy = cpy2`

now look for all keys in cpy, where  cpy[key] == key
you know that for these values you have cycles of length n and if you want you can reconstruct them by starting with key in d and iterate n times

Second iteration for cycle length n=3:
follow instructions from first iteration.

Iterate till cycle length n == N

With this approach you should be able to identify all loops.
However if you had a loop of length n you had n solutions for the same loop.

Example if you had loop [9, 10, 15] then you would find:
[10, 15, 9] and also [15, 10, 9] So you should probable eliminate or never even store any solution where the first value in a loop is not the smallest value in the list of values

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def get_cycles(d):
    cycles = []

    while d:
        # Keep track of keys we've iterated through in this loop
        tracked = []

        # Take the next available key
        k = next(iter(d))

        while True:
            tracked.append(k)

            # This key (the value of the previous key) must have already 
            # been deleted, meaning it was part of a cycle or lead to 
            # repetitions of an already discovered cycle
            try:
                v = d[k]
            except KeyError:
                # Always delete keys leading up to the current key too, as this
                # same loop will happen every time we land on one of these keys
                # otherwise
                for t in tracked:
                    if t in d:
                        del d[t]
                break

            # If the value of the current key was one of the keys leading up to
            # the current key, we've discovered a cycle starting from the value
            # of the current key and ending at the current key
            if v in tracked:
                cycle = tracked[tracked.index(v):]
                cycles.append(cycle)
                for c in cycle:
                    del d[c]
                break

            # If the value of the current key is a key in any of the
            # previously discovered cycles, we want to delete this sequence,
            # as we've already discovered the cycle it leads to
            if any(v in cycle for cycle in cycles):
                for t in tracked:
                    del d[t]
                break

            # Set the next key
            k = v

    return cycles


d1 = {1: 5, 2: 14, 3: 15, 4: 3, 5: 5, 6: 5, 7: 15, 8: 6, 9: 10, 10: 15, 11: 12, 12: 15, 13: 14, 14: 8, 15: 9}
d2 = {1:6, 3:1, 6:3}

print(get_cycles(d1))
print(get_cycles(d2))
```

Output:

```
[[5], [15, 9, 10]]
[[1, 6, 3]]
```

Algorithm keeps track of each key it iterates through, iterating by setting key equal to its own value.

If a key's value is already in the list of iterated keys, a cycle has been discovered from that position in the iterated key list to the end. The tracked keys that lead to the discovery of this cycle must then be deleted from the dictionary, as this loop has already been traversed.

If a key's value is a key in one of the previously discovered cycles, then the current sequence of traversed keys must be deleted from the dictionary, as the cycle to which this sequence leads has already been discovered.

And if a key's value is no longer a key itself (raising a KeyError when the key's value is tested as a key), the loop breaks because that key must already have been deleted, meaning it was part of a cycle or part of a sequence that lead into a cycle.